# How to add am/pm to a category of data in R

Tags: r, datetime

I would like to change my category of data weightLog_data[["Date"]] which currently appears like this 2016-05-02 23:59:00 to this 2016-05-02 11:59 PM. here is dput. thank you thank you. I am then using as.posixct to change from character to datetime. Thank you

```
structure(list(Id = c(1503960366, 1503960366, 1927972279, 2873212765, 
2873212765, 4319703577, 4319703577, 4558609924, 4558609924, 4558609924
), Date = c("5/2/2016 23:59", "5/3/2016 23:59", "4/13/2016 1:08", 
"4/21/2016 23:59", "5/12/2016 23:59", "4/17/2016 23:59", "5/4/2016 23:59", 
"4/18/2016 23:59", "4/25/2016 23:59", "5/1/2016 23:59"), WeightKg = c(52.59999847, 
52.59999847, 133.5, 56.70000076, 57.29999924, 72.40000153, 72.30000305, 
69.69999695, 70.30000305, 69.90000153), WeightPounds = c(115.9631465, 
115.9631465, 294.31712, 125.0021043, 126.3248746, 159.6146812, 
159.3942223, 153.66219, 154.984977, 154.1031246), Fat = c(22L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 25L, NA, NA, NA, NA), BMI = c(22.64999962, 22.64999962, 
47.54000092, 21.45000076, 21.69000053, 27.45000076, 27.37999916, 
27.25, 27.45999908, 27.31999969), IsManualReport = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), LogId = c(1.46e+12, 
1.46e+12, 1.46e+12, 1.46e+12, 1.46e+12, 1.46e+12, 1.46e+12, 1.46e+12, 
1.46e+12, 1.46e+12)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The standard format for a `datetime` object in R is `2016-05-02 23:59:00`. You can convert it to other format but it will no longer a `datetime`, but a pure text object. Do you know that?

Answer (score 0):

you could try the `lubridate` package to convert the Date column into datetime directly.

```
weightLog_data$Date <- lubridate::mdy_hm(weightLog_data$Date)
```

Comment: not what I am looking for. I already am converting using posixct what I am trying to do is add am/pm and convert out military before or during process of converting to datetime.

Comment: you can use `%` codes to parse and format datetime using this resource: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

Comment: an example with the first `Date` value is here: `format(strptime("5/2/2016 23:59", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")`, which parses it from character to datetime, then into the requested AM/PM format.

Comment: okay great thank you yes this works perfectly, so this is after conversion to date time using posixct? In addition, does strptime require package download? Thank you

Comment: how would I run this for entire column of data weightLog_info$Date? thank you

Comment: This is what I try but receive all NA 
weightLog_data[['Date']] <- format(strptime(weightLog_data[['Date']], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")

Comment: I found mistake in "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p) change dashes to forward slash in the change format line of datetime.

Comment: I did find another problem, strptime leaves in chr not datetime